# Display only one TextBox which is bound to selected item from ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, datatemplate, listviewitem

I have a `ListView` which is bound to an ObservableCollection
I have added a `DataTemplate` to a `ListView` to bind item with TextBox in purpose to `Rename` selectedItem using Rename from ContextMenu:

**View**

```
        <ListView DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                  Background="MidnightBlue"
                  Width="140"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNotebook, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Notebooks}"
                  x:Name="notebooksList"
                  SelectionChanged="notebooksList_SelectionChanged"
                  SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <uc:DisplayNotebook Notebook="{Binding}">
                            <uc:DisplayNotebook.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Rename"
                                              Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=EditCommand}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedNotebook}"/>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                                              Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=DeleteNotebookCommand}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedNotebook}"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </uc:DisplayNotebook.ContextMenu>
                        </uc:DisplayNotebook>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=IsVisible}"
                                 x:Name="notebookTextBox">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=EndEditingCommand}"
                                                           CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**ViewModel**

```
        public async void StopEditingNotebook(Notebook notebook)
        {
            IsVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
            await DatabaseHelper.Update(notebook);
            GetNotebooks();
        }

        public async void StopEditingNote (Note note)
        {
            IsVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
            await DatabaseHelper.Update(note);
            GetNotes();
        }
```

**Commands**

```
  public class EndEditingCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public NotesVM ViewModel { get; set; }

        public EndEditingCommand(NotesVM vm)
        {
            ViewModel = vm;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            Notebook notebook = parameter as Notebook;
            if (notebook != null)
                ViewModel.StopEditingNotebook(notebook);
        }
    }
```

```
public class EditCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public NotesVM ViewModel { get; set; }

        public EditCommand(NotesVM vm)
        {
            ViewModel = vm;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ViewModel.StartEditing();
        }
    }
```

I'd like to `Rename` only one item at once by popping up one TextBox instead of all TextBoxes in the same time(this what is happening currently due to bound TextBox in DataTemplate).

I was wondering about finding an `ID` of selectedItem and then somehow display only this particular TextBox.

Do you have any ideas on this matter?
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `MultiDataTrigger` to toggle the `Visibility` of the `TextBox`. The conditions are `IsSelected` and `IsVisible` from your view model.

Alternatively (recommended), spend your item model an `IsEditEnabled` property (or move and rename the `IsVisible` property to the item model).

Currently, every item binds to the same `IsVisible` property of the same `ViewModel` instance.
Instead, each item must bind to its own property (that's why the property should be defined in the item model).

Note, a member named with the prefix "is" is expected to return a boolean.
In your case it would be semantically correct to name the property `Visibility` and not `IsVisible`.

Additionally, the `CommandParameter` binding inside the `ContextMenu` looks wrong too. It must be

```xml
<ContextMenu>
  <MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
I've added IsVisible property to item model, but still in View it's connected to initial value and I don't know how to split it to particular items. Can you help me with it?